# finding a way to track website users

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know that is there any way to know after which page an user is leaving the website.

So that I can track that page and work to improve the content of that page.

I am using PHP as backend code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see which is the last page a user is visiting, you can do something like this

I am assuming that you have a mysql connection already provided.
Create a page like "session.php" and place this function

```
function trackpage($pagename) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
       // if the user is visiting the website for the first time
       session_start();
       $query = "INSERT INTO `newusers` VALUES(NULL, '$pagename');";
       //In case table 'newuser' have two fields 'id' and 'page' to keep a track of page
       $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
       $_SESSION['userid'] = mysql_insert_id();
    }
    else {
       //if he is just visiting another page
       $query = "UPDATE `newusers` SET page='$pagename' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['userid']."';";
       $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());   
    }
}
```

Npw you need to include this on every page. on the top write this

```
<?
include "session.php";
trackpage("index.php");
?>
```

Now you know on what page are people leaving the website

Comment: Try to think it over a little more ;)

Comment: @col. Sharpnel, this is just a demonstration of an easy way, OP should be able to use it the way it fits him

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to add [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics) to your site.

The harder way would be to create a session for every visitor, and store in the database the last visited page. This has no guarantee they left the site for a reason such as "I did not like it", they may have clicked on a link that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite precise.
Just track all hits and use timeouts to separate continuous page visits from page leavings.
That's all

Comment: Sharpnel, my post is just a demonstration of an easy way, OP should be able to use it the way it fits him